Can I read uninitialized bytes/padding by laundering through C FFI?
My chain of reasoning is

I can convert any struct into [MaybeUninit<u8>; size_of_struct], including padding bytes
I'm allowed to pass an uninitialized buffer to a C function to initialize.
In C, unlike in Rust, I can "initialize" bytes by simply treating them as initialized (afaik). (reference for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11965368)

use core::mem::MaybeUninit;

extern "C" {
  // Defined in a C source file as
  //   void *identity(void *p) { return p; }
  fn identity(p: *const MaybeUninit<u8>) -> *const u8;
}

pub fn convert_to_bytes_including_padding<T>(x: *const T) -> *const [u8] {
  let x_maybe_uninit_bytes = x as *const MaybeUninit<u8>;
  unsafe {
    let x_bytes = identity(x_maybe_uninit_bytes);
    core::slice::from_raw_parts(x_bytes, core::mem::size_of::<T>())
  }
}

Edit: based on discussion, it seems like this might partially simplify to the question of "If rust code receives a buffer of u8 from an extern C function, e.g. malloc, is it automatically undefined behavior to assign that buffer type *const u8 if the implementation of that C function is not guaranteed to have initialized all bytes", e.g. is this unsound (bearing in mind that c_void is #[repr(u8)]. I may ask it as a separate question.
fn get_arbitrary_bytes(n: usize) -> *const u8 {
    let x: *const c_void = unsafe { libc::malloc(n) };
    x as *const u8
}


The answers you link support that getting the address of a variable would make the variable's value indeterminate, not simply that a pointer exists (that would be insane). I still have my doubts, but even taking that as gospel, that doesn't apply in this Rust<->C ffi scenario.

Simply passing a pointer does not inform or instruct to the underlying system that some memory value is initialized. And thus it should still be considered uninitialized back on the Rust side, since... to point out the obvious... you did not initialize it.

@kmdreko I think that the idea of the OP is that using uninitialized memory is UB from a compiler POV, only. And since the Rust compiler doesn't know what that C function does, it could initialize the memory, for example with random values, and the bits in that memory will have some particular value. So from the compiler point of view, that memory shall be treated as initialized. Naturally now that cross-language LTO is a thing, unless that call is a dynamic library, I wouldn't be too sure.

@rodrigo sure, the Rust compiler will assume that the memory is initialized, however the fact that it isn't means its still UB. And even if its unlikely for anything to go wrong, it is still possible that things go wrong if you try to use memory you haven't written to. "Uninitialized memory" is not just a compiler abstraction: trap representations exist in hardware, reading from unwritten OS pages may not yield consistent results or can even fault, and even more esoteric platforms exist that can trip you up if you don't play by the rules.

@kmdreko those are valid but special case concerns. I'm dealing with u8 which doesn't have trap representations on hardware I care about, I am in a context where it's guaranteed that I'm not dealing with "esoteric platforms", I am in a context where I can guarantee that the OS page has been zeroed at some point prior, etc. You're answering "is it possible for things to go wrong", I'm interested in something closer to "is it possible for things to go right"

@rodrigo basically as you say. Do you expect that cross-language LTO imposes the rust compiler's definitions of UB on C code?

Still if you ask about the Rust language, you can't do what you're trying to do, you promised things that you did not uphold (you basically told the compiler you've initialized something when you didn't).

@kmdreko also, let's keep in mind that algorithms that rely on accessing garbage uninitialized memory have been well-known for decades, e.g. https://research.swtch.com/sparse. It certainly isn't common but I'm not insane.

@ajp Neat link, but not convincing. Even in C99 (its definitely UB in C90) those reads could still fault on indeterminate values (via trap representation or other memory protection). There are many nuances to consider if you actually need such techniques to work and not something you should really consider.

Though, no I don't actually expect anything to go wrong using what you propose. But you are still lying to the compiler, and if it gets wise to your tricks you may have a bad time.

I would have thought that in order for the Rust declaration that the extern C function returns a pointer to initialized memory to be correct, the C function must return a pointer to memory that is initialized per Rust's memory model.  Otherwise the correct declaration for that extern C function would be a return type of pointer to MaybeUninit.

@kmdreko setting aside C99, that algorithm (like any algorithm) could be implemented in platform-specific assembly. Then, if there is a useful algorithm which is possible to implement and run on a given processor, it's reasonable to ask "[how] can I implement this algorithm in Rust (to run on that same given processor)?"

@eggyal interesting. Note that libc::malloc in the stdlib returns a pointer to uninitialized memory, which is not wrapped in MaybeUninit (see edit to the question)

Pointers do not have the same validity requirements that references do. There's nothing wrong with *const u8 regardless whether the memory it points is initialized or not. If you were to try to make it a slice, then you'd need MaybeUninit (e.g. &[MaybeUninit<u8>]).

Yes, I should have been more clear that I was referring to what the pointer type would need to be in order for dereferencing to be valid.

This is essentially (part of) UCG#331 - Can inline assembly reads read uninit and violate noalias?:

pub unsafe fn freeze_u8(p: *const u8) -> u8 {
    let ret: u8;
    std::arch::asm!(
        "mov al, byte ptr [rdi]",
        in("rdi") p,
        lateout("al") ret, options(nostack)
    );
    ret
}


Inline assembly is the same as FFI as both are unknown for the Abstract Machine.
To this question @RalfJung replied:

Inline assembly is generally only allowed to do things to the AM state that Rust code could also do. So, it can not violate noalias (...)
If inline assembly just reads those bytes (outside the AM) but entirely ignores their content, then this is unobservable, so I agree that would be fine (...)
The same is also true for the uninit memory question. However, I can't think of an optimization that would be broken by implementing freeze via inline assembly... (assuming your target guarantees that all register reads are always safe, no electrically floating lines or NaT). That said, there are some formal arguments the compiler can make about how certain bit patterns are unobservable by Rust programs and hence it can do whatever it wants with them, and inline assembly could violate such reasoning. Not sure if this would ever cause a problem.

So, in conclusion, you should avoid it. This is in no way a definite T-opsem decision, though.
In some way, this is actually worse than this issue, since no read was actually performed by C, so it is easier to argue that uninit was not removed.
